# need silverlight 3 development 

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, msbuild

At work, I am on a sizable development team.  Our current project is in Silverlight 3.  We cannot upgrade right now due to all the regression testing (company policy)

Well, our LAN dept worked on my dev box and they uninstalled silverlight 3.  Now the project will not load due to :

*The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

I cannot find anywhere I can re-install the required silverlight v3 files.

Development on my PC is at a stop - Please Help!

Comment: You abviously do not know our LAN dept!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you haven't installed the Silverlight 3 SDK on the box. [One quick search](http://www.google.com/search?q=silverlight+3+sdk) gets you to the [Silverlight 3 SDK download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1ea49236-0de7-41b1-81c8-a126ff39975b&displaylang=en).

Comment: Its all in how you write the search isn't it :-) Thanks for the quick reply, I searched the web (google, of course) for sliverlight 3 for hours!! Argg) You are a life savor! Or, at least a job savor!